# Apple iCloud calendar API

Tags: calendar, icloud

I've been trying to find out of its possible to access Apple's iCloud calendar from a web application.

Does it support CalDAV or any sort of web API? I can't seem to find a clear answer for this.

Answer (score 14):

iCloud uses CalDAV. A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=icloud+caldav) returns this [hint for determining server URL info](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20111014102515403) for use with iCal on Mac OS 10.6 -- but once you have that info you should be able to use it with any CalDAV client.